# Netezza error - Missing values in datafile cause: ERROR [HY000] Parse error in the data file

Tags: netezza

I'm currently working with the Netezza appliance v7.1 using Aginity Version 4.3.1671.22924.

I'm trying to load data from a textfile by creating an external table. The textfile is tab-separated and contains missing values (which are causing the error). The SQL-command, which I pass to the Aginity Query Analyzer, is executed 'successfull' - but when try to get a view of the data, the error message "Error [HY000] Parse error in the data file" is returned.

My data file looks something like this:

```
1   NYT 2009 
2       2010
3   CTIO    2010
```

The first column is an ID, the second a name and the third year.

Note that the second column has a missing observation in second row - if I fill it out, there is no error. Also, If I put the missing value in the third column, there is no error either.

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TESTLOAD( 
>       id varchar(3) null, 
>       name varchar(5) null, 
>       year integer null
>       )
>   USING (
>       dataobject('address of the txt file containing data')
>       remotesource 'ODBC' 
>       delimiter '\t' 
>       fillRecord true ); 
>       
>       select * from TESTLOAD;

The external table TESTLOAD is created successfully, but the view 'select * from TESTLOAD' cannot be executed for some reason that involves the missing values.

My hope was that the fillRecord option would handle the missing values but I might be misunderstanding the manual there.

Does anybody know how to handle the issue?

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Your example works for me unmodified (except for the update of the dataobject reference to my file location, and re-tabbing the data because how it pasted). fillRecord only comes into play when you have fewer columns in an input row than are defined in the table. Your second row presumably has the tab delimiting the second column but there's no data there so it will be stored as an empty string.  For debug purposes you might try changing the delimiter to ',' to make sure something didn't go wonky with the tabs.  Also, take a look the NullValue option to understand how Nulls are handled.